# How to use the centroid detected by Kalman filter with Hungarian algorithm to associate moving targets in upper and lower frames?

Tags: c++, opencv, tracking, kalman-filter, hungarian-algorithm

How to use the Hungarian algorithm to correlate the corresponding targets between two consecutive frames, and finally realize that it can judge whether the moving target in the next frame is already existing or new? I do not how to start in the actual implementation of the program using C++ and Opencv3 library?

Now I can get the centroids of the moving target detected by kalman filter in each frame.

//This is part of the main function.

```
kalmanv.clear();
initKalman(0, 0);
Point s, p;//s:kalmanCorrect,p:kalmanPredict

//variable definition
vector<vector<Point>> contours;//rectangular frame position around the contour
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
int count = 0;
Mat frame, gray, mogMask;
char numText[8];

while (capture.read(frame)) {
    ...
    findContours(mogMask, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    //definition of moment and center moment
    vector<Moments> mu(contours.size());
    vector<Point2f> mc(contours.size());

    ...
        mu[t] = moments(contours[t], false);//calculate moment
        mc[t] = Point2f(mu[t].m10 / mu[t].m00, mu[t].m01 / mu[t].m00);//calculate center moment
        measurement(0) = mc[t].x;
        measurement(1) = mc[t].y;

        p = kalmanPredict();
        Point center = Point(selection.x + (selection.width / 2), selection.y + (selection.height / 2));//calculate centroid
        s = kalmanCorrect(center.x, center.y);
                    //I don't know what to do next.



}
```

I have got the set of centroids points for the moving target, and then how to use the data in conjunction with the Hungarian algorithm?

Comment: Are you sure the Hungarian Algorithm is what you need here?

Comment: I am not sure. I need to match the multi-target centroids of the top frame and the bottom frame to avoid repeating the same target count. This seems to be the case in the matlab program. Could you please tell me what to do next? Thank you in advance.